# Build a Python library that depends on one specific class from where this library is going to be used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a Python library `magic_lib` in which I need to instantiate a Python class (let's call it `SomeClass`) which is defined in the Python application that would import `magic_lib`.

What's the appropriate way to use/work on `SomeClass` when I develop `magic_lib`, since I don't have `SomeClass` in the `magic_lib` repo?

I'm thinking to create a dummy `SomeClass` like this. During packaging, I then exclude this class.

```
from typing import Any


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, *arg: Any, **kwargs: Any):
        pass
```

I'm wondering if this is the right approach. If not, any suggestions how I could approach this problem.

Thanks.

Additional thoughts: maybe I could use `importlib` like this?

```
my_module = importlib.import_module('some.module.available.in.production')
some_class = my_module.SomeClass()
```

#### Here is a more specific example:

Let's say I have two repos: `workflows` and `magic_lib`. Within `workflows`, it has defined a class named `Task`. Generally, we define tasks directly within the `workflows` repo. Everything works just fine. Now, let's say, I want to use `magic_lib` to programmatically define tasks in the `workflows` repo. Something like the following in the `workflows` repo:

```
from magic_lib import Generator

tasks: List[Task] = Generator().generate_tasks()
```

In order to do that, within `magic_lib`, I need to somehow have access to the class `Task` so that I can have it returned through the function `generate_tasks()`. I cannot really import `Task` defined in `workflows` from `magic_lib`. My question is how I can have access to `Task` within `magic_lib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

## Original question:

---

In python, there are decorators:

```
from <MY_PACKAGE> import add_method

@add_method
class MyClass:
    def old_method(self):
        print('Old method')
```

Decorators are functions which take classes/functions/... as argument:

```
def add_method(cls):
    class Wrapper(cls):
        def new_method(self):
            print('New method')
    return Wrapper
```

`MyClass` is passed as the `cls` argument to the add_method decorator function. The function can return a new class which inherits from `MyClass`

```
x = MyClass()
x.old_method()
x.new_method()
```

We can see that the method has been added. YAY !

So to recap, decorators are a great way to pass your user's custom class to your library. Decorators are just functions so they are easy to handle.

---

## Modified question:

---

Classes can be passed to functions and methods as arguments

```py
from magic_lib import generate_five_instances

tasks: List[Task] = generate_five_instances(Task)
```

```py
def generate_five_instances(cls):
    return [cls() for _ in range(5)]
```

If you come from another language, you might find this weird, but classes are **FIRST CLASS CITIZENS** in Python. That means you can assign them to variables and pass them as arguments.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, but that's not what I'm looking for. Let me rephrase a little bit in the original question.

Comment: I just added a more specific example. Hopefully, it could make sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks. Passing in the required Class is much simpler!